# Maven mojo plugin, how to define phases that must be triggered before this goal?

Tags: maven-2, mojo

hey, 
I have a deploy pojo plugin (deploying a war to a remote server).  I have the remote-deploy plugin in the build section of pom definition, I need package phase to be triggered before deploy-remote goal, for it the war be already created before I secure-copy it to a remote server.

With the execution elements (according to a documentation), I can attach my goal to a particular phase, for instance bind it to the phase after, so in my case, install phase ...but that's just a workaround.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-hello-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sayhi</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

simply put, if I place only my goal into the build section, and run it, package phase is not run before. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maven Mojo plugin, how to define phases that must be triggered before this goal ?

You can't.

> I have the remote-deploy plugin in the build section of pom definition, I need package phase to be triggered before deploy-remote goal, for it the war be already created before I secure-copy it to a remote server.

Just bind it to the `package` phase, your goal will be called after the goals bounds to `package` by default (so the war will be there).

Here is an example demonstrating this behavior with the Maven AntRun plugin configured like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <echo message="Hi!!!!!"/>
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And the output of `mvn package`:

```
$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Q3934833 Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Q3934833 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test (default-test) @ Q3934833 ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1:war (default-war) @ Q3934833 ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [Q3934833] in [/home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3934833/target/Q3934833]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3934833/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [317 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3934833/target/Q3934833.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (default) @ Q3934833 ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] Hi!!!!!
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

The antrun plugin is executed after `package`, as expected.

Comment: I tried it this way, and the war was not created. I tried exactly as it is in the example I pasted and I got "war does not exist"

Comment: It works with the install phase, but not with package...but that workaround wouldn't be good, because I'd have to always install the artifact before deployment

Comment: @lisak It just works as advertised. If you get a different behavior, show your configuration and the output demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I should probably go to sleep :-) I was running "mvn myGoal:myPhase" instead of "mvn package" ... so this is OK finally, thank you

Comment: @lisak No problem, glad we got it sorted out.

Comment: **You can shorten the Configuration** by removing the `<phase>` and set the `defaultPhase` in the `@Mojo`-Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use PREPARE_PACKAGE phase in your @Mojo annotation:

```
@Mojo(name = "myName", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PREPARE_PACKAGE)
```